# vim: same syntax highlighting for different file extensions

Tags: vim

Is there a way to make same syntax highlighting for different file extensions?

e.g: Same highlighting for

```
foo.c and foo.my_c_extension
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vim will set the syntax highlighting based on a buffer's `filetype`. You may set the `filetype` via `autocmd` to match multiple file extensions.

For example, when a file is loaded or created in a buffer having the `.c` or `.my_c_extension` extensions, the `filetype` will be set to `c`:

```
" In .vimrc, for example:
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.c,*.my_c_extension set filetype=c
```

See `:help filetype` and `:help autocmd` for more information.

According to the `filetype` help, you may create `~/.vim/ftdetect/file_extension.vim` which contains the `autocmd`. That will be loaded after other rules, allowing you to override settings previously made by Vim or plugins.  This may be preferable to setting it in your `.vimrc`.

```
" File: ~/.vim/ftdetect/my_c_extension.vim
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.my_c_extension set filetype=c
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the filetype to be the same, (maybe that has some unwanted side effects), and just want to set the syntax, you can use the following:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.my_c_extension set syntax=c
```